# Angular11: How can a component get informed about changes in state passed to the route?

Tags: angular

I have a (login) component that gets state passed with the route. As far as I know, passed state can be read via `Router.router.getCurrentNavigation()?.extras.state` in the constructor and via `history.state` in other code, like in `ngOnInit`. This works if the component is being instatiated for the current route.

However I have a case where the component is not being instatiated for a new route because an instance already exists.

My question is how the component can get informed about changes in the state passed with the new route. I could not find any event I could use (like with `ActivatedRoute.paramMap.subscribe(...)` for route parameters). I found that `history.state` does not store my own state in routing events, hence events could not be used for my problem.

My use case is: A route is guarded by a authentication route card, passed to `canResolve` in the route definition. The route guard navigates to /login if the user is not authenticated. The return URL should be passed via state (not via a parameter). If the user klicks on one links for a guarded route (in the navigation bar), the login component gets the return URL from the state. If the user then clicks on another guarded link, the login component does not get the updated return URL.

I know that using a route parameter would solve my problem, but this is not the point. I generally want to know if a component can react to changes in passed route state.

Comment: How are you passing the state? What would be an example of a route with state you’d like to know about?

Comment: I am passing the state when routing in code: 

export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) { }
 
    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
        if (this.authService.isAuthenticated) {
            return true;
        }
        else {  
   this.router.navigate(['/login'], { state: { returnUrl: state.url }
  }
 }
}

The route with state would be /login.

Answer (score 0):

One option, you maybe able to implement a custom/your own like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46813552/6085193) `Subscribe/Fire on navigation/route` events in app.component and firing AuthGuard, then save the state and access it as needed or save old routes

```
constructor(
  private router: Router,
  private route: ActivatedRoute,
  private authGuard: AuthGuard,
) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.router.events
    .subscribe(event => {
      if (event instanceof RoutesRecognized) {
        this.guardRoute(event);
      }
    }));
}

private guardRoute(event: RoutesRecognized): void {
  if (this.isPublic(event)) {
    return;
  }

  if (!this.callCanActivate(event, this.authGuard)) {
    return;
  }
}
   
private callCanActivate(event: RoutesRecognized, guard: CanActivate) {
 
  return guard.canActivate(this.route.snapshot, event.state);
}

private isPublic(event: RoutesRecognized) {
  return event.state.root.firstChild.data.isPublic;
}
```