# Router navigate inside NavigationStart event

Tags: javascript, angular, routes, navigation

I need to restrict access to some pages and if the user tries to access the page, I need it to be redirected to home page. So for this I have the following code :

```
this.router
    .events
    .subscribe(
        (event) => {
            if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
                if (!AllowedRoutes.includes(event.url)) {
                    this.router.navigate(['/']);
                }
            }
        }
    );
```

Where `AllowedRoutes` is an array with all the allowed route urls like the following:

```
export const AllowedRoutes: any = [
    '/allowed-route-one',
    '/allowed-route-two',
    '/allowed-route-three'
];
```

When I use `this.router.navigate(['/']);` it is showing an error in console that says `Maximum call stack size exceeded`

How can this be fixed or is there any better way to allow some URLs only instead of adding a guard in every route to check if the route is in the array.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're navigating to `/` with `this.router.navigate(['/']);` which is not an element of `AllowedRoutes`. This creates the loop, because every navigation to `/` is gonna be redirected to `/`.

For global `RouteGuards`, have a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41219439/angular2-global-guard-user-has-to-be-logged-in-always).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just have added a condition that is && event.url !== '/'